# I have a web page I made with a slideshow, but the slidshow moves across the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a simple website just for fun with a cool little slideshow in it but something went wrong.. When ever i resize the screen the entire slideshow moves to the left. I would like the other elements to move over it and it to stay in one place. How can i fix something like this?? The code is bellow along with an images link! Thanks:)

Html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Home
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
  <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.18.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
 </head>
 <body class="body" onload="Slider()">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="bg">
    <div class="mainHeader">
     <nav>
      <ul>
       <li class="last">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="topArea">
     <div class="topAInfo">
      <h2>
       Here is just a simple title
      </h2>
      <p>
       This is just a little bit of dummy text. This is just a little bit of dummy text. This is just a little bit of dummy text. This is just a little bit of dummy text.
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middleArea">
     <div class="slider">
      <img id="1" src="slide1.jpg" border="0" alt="slide1">
      <img id="2" src="slide2.jpg" border="0" alt="slide2"> 
      <img id="3" src="slide3.jpg" border="0" alt="slide3">
     </div>
     <div class="middleAInfo">
      <h3>
       Welcome to
      </h3>
      <p>
       A dummy website!!<br/>
       <span class="info">Our law offices are the best in the world! They are recommended by so many different advisors!</span>
      </p>
     </div>
     <div class="latestNews">
      <hr>
      <h2>
       Latest News
      </h2>
      <div class="post">
       <p class="date">
        March 28, 2015
       </p>
       <p>
        New advanced update with double speed and a whole bunch of cool new st.. <a href="#">more&gt;&gt;</a>
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="post">
       <p class="date">
        March 28, 2015
       </p>
       <p>
        New advanced update with double speed and a whole bunch of cool new st.. <a href="#">more&gt;&gt;</a>
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="newsLetter">
       <div class="newsLInfo">
        <h3>
         Newsletter sign-up
        </h3>
        <hr>
        <p>
         If you would like to sign up for our free NewsLetter please enter your email below
        </p><a href="#">Unsubscribe</a>
       </div><input type="text" name="textBox" class="textBox" style="width:200px; height:20px;">
       <div class="button1">
        Submit
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div><!--https://www.freelancer.com/jobs/php/PSD-HTML-page-only-page/-->
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
@font-face {
    font-family: SketchFont;
    src: url(Fonts/Sketch_Block.ttf);
}
body{
 background:#ebebeb;
 width:80%;
 height:1300px;
}
.container{
 width:100%;
}
.mainHeader nav{
 width:95%;
 height:40px;
 position:relative;
 left:30px;
 top:60px;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75),rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75),rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75),rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(90, 215, 240, 0.75),rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* Standard syntax */
 /*margin: 100px 50px 0 150px;*/
}
.mainHeader nav ul{

}
.mainHeader nav ul li{
 float:right;
 display:inline;
 text-align:center;
 border:1px solid #ADADA8;
 border-bottom:none;
 border-top:none;
 border-left:none;
 padding-top:20px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li.last{
 border-right:none;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 /*margin:10px Use to replace paddings right/left but causes hovedr errors*/
 font-family:Arial;
 position:relative;
 top:-10px;
 color:white;
 padding:10px;
 padding-right:20px;
 padding-left:20px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a.active{
 background:white;
 color:black;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a:hover{
 background:white;
 color:black;
}
.topArea{
 width:95%;
 height:300px;
 position:relative;
 left:30px;
 top:10px;
 /*margin: -50px 50px 0 150px;*/
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white,rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(white,rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(white,rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(white,rgb(33, 171, 198)); /* Standard syntax */
}
.topArea .topAInfo{
 margin:20px;
 padding-top:60px;
 width:60%;
 margin:50px;
 font-family:;
}
.topArea .topAInfo h2{
 font-family:SketchFont;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.topArea .topAInfo p{
 line-height:25px;
 font-family:cursive;
 font-size:15px;
}
.bg{
 width:100%;
 height:1200px;
 position:relative;
 left:10%;
 background:linear-gradient(blue, white, white, blue); /* Standard syntax */
 /*background-image:url(bg2.jpg);*/
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.middleArea{
 background:linear-gradient(white, white, #55C4E9); /* Standard syntax */;
 height:700px;
 width:95%;
 position:relative;
 left:30px;
 top:10px;
}
.middleArea .middleAInfo {
 padding:30px 0 0 30px;
 width:400px;
 
}
.middleArea .middleAInfo p{
 color:#49CBF0;
 font-size:30px;
 font-weight:400;
 position:relative;
 top:-515px;
}
.middleArea .middleAInfo p span{
 color:black;
 font-size:20px;
 font-weight:400;
}
.middleArea .middleAInfo h3{
 position:relative;
 top:-520px;
}

.middleArea .latestNews {
 width:250px;
 height:300px;
 background:#0099cc;
 float:right;
 position:relative;
 top:-475px;
 border:1px solid #D6D8D8;
}
.middleArea .latestNews hr{
 position:relative;
 top:50px;
 color:black;
 width:90%;
 margin-left:10px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews h2{
 padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
 color:white;
}
.middleArea .latestNews p.date{
 color:white;
 font-size:13px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:10px 10px 10px 20px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews p{
 color:white;
 font-size:13px;
 position:relative;
 left:10px;
 width:225px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews a{
 color:blue;
 font-size:15px;
 font-family:Arial;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter{
 background:white;
 width:250px;
 height:200px;
 position:relative;
 top:80px;
 border:1px solid #D6D8D8;
 left:-2px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter .textBox{
 position:relative;
 top:40px;
 left:25px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter .button1{
 width:50px;
 height:25px;
 background:#1768ED;
 padding:3px 10px 2px 10px;
 border-radius:7px;
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 font-family:Arial;
 position:relative;
 top:45px;
 left:155px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter .button1:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter h3{
 position:relative;
 top:15px;
 left:10px;
 color:#21AFEA;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter hr{
 position:relative;
 top:20px;
 color:#21AFEA;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter p{
 color:black;
 position:relative;
 top:40px;
 color:#21AFEA;
 font-size:15px;
}
.middleArea .latestNews .newsLetter a{
 position:relative;
 top:90px;
 left:30px;
}
.slider{
 width:800px;
 height:450px;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin:30px auto;
 background-image:url(loading.gif);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 background-size: 100px 100px;
 position:relative;
 top:150px;
 left:-8%;
}
.slider img{
 display:none;
 width:700px;
 height:450px;
}
```

Javascript:

```js
 function Slider(){
  $(".slider #1").show("fade", 500);
  $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction:'left'}, 500);
  var sc = 3;
  var count = 2;

  setInterval(function(){
   $(".slider #"+count).show("slide", {direction:'right'}, 500);
   $(".slider #"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction:'left'}, 500);

   if(count == sc){
    count = 1;
   }else{
    count = count + 1;
   }
  },6500);
 }
```

Link to images-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8cxqlfp7i46066/slides.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a responsive site. There is a Jquery plugin to make existing sites responsive. Here is a link to the process.

http://speckyboy.com/2014/04/24/make-any-website-responsive/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This will Help You, Follow this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Hardy_411/9z536pq0/).
i think your code is not working because you have called the Slider function in `<Body>` rather use it in `JavaScript.` Call `Slider()` in to `$(document).ready();`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Slider();
});
```

Other stuff you will find on jsfiddle.